# Fastest Text search method in a large text file

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am doing a text search in a rather big txt file (100k lines, 7mo)
Text is not that big but I need a lot of searches.
I want to look for a target string and return the line where it appears.
My text file is formatted so that the target can only appear in one line.

What is the most efficient way? I do a lot of searches so I want to improve speed.
Here is mycode right now:

```
def lookup_line(target):
    #returns line of the target, or None if doesnt exist
    line=None
    dir=os.path.dirname(__file__)
    path=dir+'/file.txt'
    file=open(path,'r')
    while line==None:
        l=file.readline()
        l=unicode(l,'utf-8')
        if target in l:
            break
        if l=='': break #happens at end of file, then stop loop
    line=l
    if line=='':line=None #end of file, nothing has been found
    file.close()
    return line
```

I use this python code for a google Appengine app.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you searching for words, phrases, or funky punctuated text (like compiler errors)? Does the file change between searches?

Comment: I am searching for words in non latin characters .
Format is :" 你好 [" 
This is due to file formatting, I need the 2 spaces and the [ to make sure the word is found at the right place in the line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Load the whole text in RAM at once. Don't read line by line.
2. Search for the pattern in the blob. If you find it, use `text.count('\n',0,pos)` to get the line number.
3. If you don't need the line number, look for the previous and next EOL to cut the line out of the text.

The loop in Python is slow. String searching is very fast. If you need to look for several strings, use regular expressions.

If that's not fast enough, use an external program like `grep`.

Comment: instead of using Python to do this job. Why not use solr? you can simply connect the solr functionality and use the results in python.

Answer (score 4):

If you are searching the same text file over and over, consider indexing the file.  For example, create a dictionary that maps each word to which lines it's on.  This will take a while to create, but will then make searches O(1).

If you are searching different text files, or can't index the file for some reason, you probably won't get any faster than the [KMP algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

EDIT: The index I described will only work for single word searches, not multi-word searches.  If you want to search for multiple words (any string) then you probably won't be able to index it.

Comment: Good suggestion, you can write an algorithm that will do multi-word searches off a single word index. A multi-word index would most likely be a waste of time. Also, you can store the character of the word boundary as the index. Regexes would make this a trivial task.

Comment: Good point.  At the very least it will be easy to determine if a line contains all the words in the sentence.  However I don't think that searches on parts of words ("uick brown fo" for example) will be indexable in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

First, don't explicitly decode bytes.

```
from io import open
```

Second, consider things like this.

```
with open(path,'r',encoding='UTF-8') as src:
    found= None
    for line in src:
        if len(line) == 0: break #happens at end of file, then stop loop
        if target in line:
            found= line
            break
    return found
```

This can be simplified slightly to use `return None` or `return line` instead of `break`.  It should run a hair faster, but it's slightly harder to make changes when there are multiple returns.

Answer (score 2):

How about 10GB/s search speeds?
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5282980/Fastest-Fulltext-Vector-Scalar-Exact-Searcher

> What is the most efficient way?

The most efficient way is using vectors, if not available then the fastest SCALAR memmem() function you can get, it happened that the article above shows them both in action, you need huge text files being traversed then the memmem() variant Railgun_NyoTengu() being **open-source in public domain** is way to go.

Comment: @Steve Sure, just wanted SO viewers to have the most recent answer/link.
Will edit it soon...