# Getting a line in a large file's content

Tags: python, performance, file, text-files, large-files

I am wondering how to implement Aaron Digulla's answer in this question:
[Fastest Text search method in a large text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449384/fastest-text-search-method-in-a-large-text-file/3449423#3449423)

```
with open ('test.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read() 
    match = re.search("abc", contents)
```

What's next, so that I can find the previous EOL and next EOL, and so that I can extract the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
match = re.search("abc", contents)
```

with

```
match = re.search("^.*abc.*$", contents, re.M)
```

It will match the whole line containing "abc". Used with `re.M` flag `^` matches the beginning of a line and `$` its end.

Here is an example:

```
import re

s = """
Twinkle, twinkle
Little star!
How I wonder 
What you are!
"""

term = "star"
match = re.search(f"^.*{term}.*$", s, re.M)
print(match.group(0))
```

It gives:

```
Little star!
```

Comment: May I also know what to do if I want the last matching line including the substring? Is re.findall() the best way? For example, I want "What you are!" but not "Little star!", when I search the character "!".

Comment: Either re.findall() or you can try to use [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module which allows searching a string in the reversed direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the start index of the match object to find the previous and next EOL using [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and [`str.rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) with their `start` and `end` parameters:

```
with open ('test.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read() 
    match = re.search("abc", contents)
    start = match.start()
    previous_EOL = contents.rfind('\n', 0, start)
    next_EOL = contents.find('\n', start)
    line = contents[previous_EOL+1: next_EOL]
```

For example:

```
contents = '''
This is a sample text
Here is 'abc' in this line.
There are some other lines.'''

match = re.search("abc", contents)
start = match.start()
previous_EOL = contents.rfind('\n', 0, start)
next_EOL = contents.find('\n', start)
line = contents[previous_EOL+1: next_EOL]

print(line)
```

Prints:

```
Here is 'abc' in this line.
```